# "Ensure that 'SQL Browser service' is running" error is received in SSAS even when SQL Browser service is running

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, sqlbrowser

I have the SQL Browser service running. Please note this points to a SQL Server 2014 Express version.

[Here is how my SQL Server Configuration Manager is shown.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDT1k.png)

[Here is the advanced view of the SQL Browser service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa481.png)

Now I'm trying to run a SSAS cube with Visual Studio 2019. Here I get the following error.

> A connection cannot be made to redirector. Ensure that 'SQL Browser' service is running.

[Here is the error message shown in the workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDndM.png)

Please note the project is connected to SQL Server 2019. Can you please help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: SQL Server Express doesn't have Analysis Services. The reason you can't connect is because the Analysis Services instance doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. @Larnu I have already installed Analysis services and can use it with Visual studio 2019. Do I need to deploy analysis services in SQL Server 2019? If so, How can I do that?

Comment: *" I have already installed Analysis services"* You can't have, again, SQL Server Express does not come with SSAS; it's only available in Standard, Development, and Enterprise editions.

Comment: I have both SQL server 2019 and 2014 Express. I think browser service runs from the Express2014 version. But my project is connected to SQL Server 2019 which is not an Express version. @Larnu

Comment: If you've installed a new SQL Server version/instance have you restarted the SQL Browser service so that it can detect it?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Yes. I restarted the browser service and even restarted the computer. But I get the same error.